# UWP touch TappedEvent works only inside TextBlock

Tags: events, uwp, textbox, windows-10, touchscreen

I'm trying to test touchscreen of a tablet (Surface) and therefore I'm developing an app that is able to detect tap event and tell its coordinates.

I made a tap event handler to main `Grid` in `MainPage` and wrote this to `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
outputText.Text = e.GetPosition(this).X.ToString() + "\t";
outputText.Text += e.GetPosition(this).Y.ToString();
```

`outputText` is just a `TextBlock` to output coordinates.

This code should give its coordinates based on `Grid`, but it only gives coordinates if I touch it within `TextBlock` area.

How does this `Tapped` event handler work in a way that it only detects tap events inside `TextBlock` and not from entire screen (app runs in fullscreen mode)?

My `MainPage.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped" PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed">
    <TextBlock x:Name="outputText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="806,374,0,0" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Grid.Background` is `null`, so the tap events pass through it. The only place where the `Grid` has any actual "surface" is the `TextBlock`, which is exactly what you are seeing.

You will have to set the background to any other value like `Transparent`. This way it will handle the events properly.